# Regex for phone number and a potentially spelled out phone number?

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex should match a potential country code prefix, (i.e `+1`), digits, spelled-out digits, and any of these potential delimiters in-between: `,`, `.`, `.`, `(`, `)`,  , `|`, `-`

---

I know there are literally thousands of phone number regex solutions online, but my research hasn't led me to a solution to my problem yet.

I need a regex to validate an input string that could have a phone number in it, possibly prefixed with a country code. This regex should also match any potential spelled-out digits.

Below are some obvious candidates that should be matched:

```
+18881234567
+3748881234567 // Armenia
18881234567
8881234567
+1888-123-4567
+1888-123-45-6-7
+18.88.123-45-6-7
8|88.123-45|6|7
+1888     1234567
+1888-   1234567
```

This part is relatively simple, the only issue I currently have is handling all the types of possible delimiters, for now, I just look for `-`, `.`, and `|`.

The other bit to this is spelled-out digits. The regex should also match (and this is only what I could think of):

```
a1888a123a4567
+1eight8eight1two345six7
8eight81234five67
8(eight)81234(five)67
8(eight-)81234(-five)67
```

I have no idea how to parse with regex and I wasn't able to find anything online.

What would be able to match these variants?

Comment: Too many examples of a wide variety.  You need to narrow down your question or give us rules for the formats you want to support.

Comment: I've update the OP, please review

Comment: Why would somebody add a phone number with `eight`. I have never known a single person ever do this

Comment: Let's suppose that there exists at least one person in 7+ billion that would.

Comment: what does "a" mean in second block? "1"?

Comment: It's just a string. Someone could write `"my phone numberis18881234567"` or `"my phone numberis888123a4567"`

Comment: It looks like actually your regex should allow everything. You can use `/.*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can validate such an input with a single regex *and* extract the actual digits comprising the phone number because if you are allowing the input to contain strings such as 'eight', presumably you would also need to translate that into '8'. So the way I would precede would be as follows:

1. First convert the input to lower case so you don't have to worry about variations such as 'eight', 'Eight', eiGhT', etc.
2. Replace occurences of 'one' with '1', 'two' with '2', etc.
3. Remove anything that is not a digit.
4. Test resulting string to have at least a single digit (i.e. its length >= 1). You may have specific rules for the number of digits, but you have not specified them.

If my assumption above is not correct, since you seem to be allowing arbitrary delimiters and alpha strings, you are essentially allowing everything as long as the input contains at least a digit. In that case you would just check for `/[0-9]|one||two|etc./i`.

Otherwise:

```js
const tests = `+18881234567
+3748881234567 // Armenia
18881234567
8881234567
+1888-123-4567
+1888-123-45-6-7
+18.88.123-45-6-7
8|88.123-45|6|7
+1888     1234567
+1888-   1234567
a1888a123a4567
+1eight8eight1two345six7
8eight81234five67
8(eight)81234(five)67
8(eight-)81234(-five)67`.split('\n');

for (const original of tests) {
    let s = original.toLowerCase();
    s = s.replace('one', '1').
        replace('two', '2').
        replace('three', '3').
        replace('four', '4').
        replace('five', '5').
        replace('six', '6').
        replace('seven', '7').
        replace('eight', '8').
        replace('nine', '9').
        replace('zero', '0');
    s = s.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '', s);
    if (s === '') {
        console.log(original + ' not valid');
    }
    else {
        console.log(original +  ' -> ' + s);
    }
}
```